# Input value is null React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm not sure what the deal is probably something stupid but when my handle email and handle password handlers are hit, I get null values for text that I entered on the form.

**LoginContainer**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'

  import * as AsyncActions from '../actions/User/UserAsyncActions'
  import Login from '../components/Login/Login'

  class LoginContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }

      this.emailIsValid = this.emailIsValid.bind(this)
      this.handleEmailInput = this.handleEmailInput.bind(this)
      this.handlePasswordInput = this.handlePasswordInput.bind(this)
      this.handleLoginPressed = this.handleLoginPressed.bind(this)
    }

    handlePasswordInput(e, password) {
      e.persist()
      this.setState(password )
    }

    handleEmailInput(e, email) {
      e.persist()
      this.setState(email)
    }

    handleLoginPressed(e) {
      e.persist()
      // e.preventDefault()
      if (this.emailIsValid(this.state.email) &&
          this.passwordIsValid(this.state.password)) {
         this.props.login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      }
    }

    emailIsValid(e, email) {
      e.persist()
      if (!email) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    }

    passwordIsValid(e, password) {
      e.persist()
      if (!password) {
        return false
      }
      return true
    }

    render(){
      return( <Login
        handleEmailInput={this.handleEmailInput}
        handlePasswordInput={this.handlePasswordInput}
        login={this.handleLoginPressed}
      /> )
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      requesting: state.user.requesting,
      loggedIn: state.user.loggedIn,
      token: state.user.token,
      session: state.user.session
    }
  }

  export const mapDispatchToProps = {
    login: AsyncActions.login
  }

  export { Login }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer)
```

**Login**

```
class Login extends Component {
  render(){
      return (
        <div>
          <LoginForm
            handleEmailInput={this.props.handleEmailInput}
            handlePasswordInput={this.props.handlePasswordInput}
            login={this.props.login}
          />
        </div>
      )
  }
}
export default Login
```

**LoginForm**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap'

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ft-login-form'>
        <PageHeader className='ft-header'>Login</PageHeader>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.login}>
          <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" >
            <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-username"
              componentClass="input"
              onChange={this.props.handleEmailInput}
              placeholder="Enter mail"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="text"
              // value={this.state.email}
            />
            <ControlLabel>Password</ControlLabel>
            <FormControl
              bsSize="small"
              className="ft-password"
              componentClass="input"
              onChange={this.props.handlePasswordInput}
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              style={{ width: 300}}
              type="text"
              // value={this.state.password}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button
            className='ft-login-button'
            type='submit'>Login</Button>
        </form>
      </div>)
  }

}

export default LoginForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right path with the `value={this.state.password}`.  But since your state is in the parent component, you have to pass the state down and the value becomes `value={this.props.value}`. The event handlers usually look something like this:

```
handlePasswordInput(e, password) {
      e.persist()
      this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
    }
```

They could be different due to the FormControl component but it's worth changing them to see if that's your problem.  Also, onChange handlers implicitly pass in `e` and you have to use a arrow function expression to explicitly pass in anything else.

Edit: If they were able to do something like you mentioned in the comment, they probably did something like this:

```
handlePasswordInput(e, password) {
      e.persist()
      const password = e.target.value
      this.setState({ password })
    }
```

In es6, `{ password }` is the same as `{ password: password}`

Comment: also are you using destructuring somehow with the {}?

Comment: it worked I do get a value with your changes.  I wonder how someone else got this working because they were able to do this:  handlePasswordInput({password}) {
      this.setState({ password})
    }

Comment: the react-bootstrap Button component takes in an onClick prop, so you could write something like`<Button
            className='ft-login-button'
            type='submit' onClick={this.props.login}>Login</Button>`.  That's what you probably want anyway, since submitting the form will refresh the page and you'll lose all your info.

Comment: hmm for some reason the call to props.login doesn't hit handleLoginPressed

Comment: ha! someone told me to use form submit, not onClick for that... which is why   I put onSubmit={this.props.login} on the <form> tag

Comment: Theres a good chance that react-bootstrap forms do something different.  Id check the docs :)

Comment: Try passing it to the onclick handler and see if it fires.  That way you know you're passing it down correctly to your component.  Then try to get the form submission working!

Comment: yea weird doesn't even work on the button, I'll investigate more thanks!  I guess if I wanna try it on the button I still need the form to submit and have and onSubmit in my <form> set to "" or something